# Googlemap v3 infoWindow auto resize after hidden div was shown

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I'm writing an web page with google map & I got some trouble;

I hava an InfoWindow which contain an hidden div, and I want to show it when I click a button in the infoWindow. But the question is when I show the hidden div the size of the infoWindow wouldn't adapt to new content automatically.

Would you please give some advices to solve this problem? Thanks a lot :-)

Here is my js:

```
function redraw() {
    var cmt = $("#bodyContent");
    cmt.show();
}

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                    '<h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h2>'+
                    '<input type="button" value="Test" onclick="redraw()" />' +
                    '<div id="bodyContent" class="test">'+
                    '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
                    'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
                    'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335 km (208 mi) '+
                    'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450 km '+
                    '(280 mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
                    'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
                    'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
                    'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
                    'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
                    'Heritage Site.</p>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '</div>';

infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    maxWidth: 300,
                    content: contentString
                 });

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    title:"Uluru (Ayers Rock)"
                 });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.open(map,marker);
                 });
```